# Load all iframes on blog asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I run a blog that features lots of videos and other framed content.

a typical blogpost body i pull from my database looks like this:

```
<p>some text</p>
<iframe src="http://example.com" width="400" height="300"></iframe>
<p>some text</p>
```

some posts have 2-3 iframes in them - the starting-page usually features 6-7  iframes.

i'd like to speed up the loading-time of my blog - is there a way i can make all iframes on my starting-page load asynchronously?

Comment: IFRAMEs are loaded asynchronously. I guess your issue as more to see with setting some logic inside window onload event. Can you post any relevant link where your issue can be check?

Comment: Hello @A.Wolff, You can access my blog at http://www.tapefruit.com/

Comment: Ya i see what you mean. I'll try to find any workaround and let you know if i find any

Comment: I think your best bet is to use a preview image and only load specific iframe once image has been clicked. There is already some plugins doing it e.g, for youtube http://www.newmediacampaigns.com/blog/lazyytjs-a-jquery-plugin-to-lazy-load-youtube-videos  You could i guess target other video provider websites with some little modifications

Comment: Try running [Yslow](http://yslow.org/) on your page. In particular, check out its recommendations to speed up your site...

Answer (score 3):

As someone said in a comment, **iframes** load asynchronously. Perhaps what you're experiencing is a slow load of the main page while it is also loading the iframes contents. I would suggest using this technique:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>speedup page with iframes</title>
<head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    some content
    <br>
    some other content
    <br>
    <iframe id="data_a"></iframe>
    <br>
    some wild content appears
    <br>
    <iframe id="data_b"></iframe>
    <br>
    some wild content appears
    <br>
    <iframe id="data_c"></iframe>
    <br>
    the end

    <script>
    $(function(){
        //the iframes will only load AFTER your
        //main page is fully loaded
        $("#data_a").attr("src", "http://domain1.com/some/path/news.html");
        $("#data_b").attr("src", "http://domain2.com/gallery/pictures.html");
        $("#data_c").attr("src", "http://domain3.com/contact/map.html");
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I'll suggest you to have all your data with you and identify the `iframes` to load and use `setTimeout` to load different set of `iframes` with some time gap.

Answer (score 2):

So, i read a lot about this topic in the last few days. Especially [this article](http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/iframe-loading-techniques-performance#dynamic) was helpful, since it discusses the actual problem I was facing: a belated `onload()` event that fires after all iframes are loaded.

After all, what I came up with are these lines of jQuery-Code that seems to work for me:

```
var src = new Array();
$(function(){
    // onDomReady() store all iframe sources in array
    $('iframe').each(function(){
      src.push($(this).attr('src'));
      $(this).attr('src', '');
    });
});

$(window).load(function() {
    // onload() restore all iframe sources from the array
    var i = 0;
    $('iframe').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', src[i]);
        i++;
    });
});
```

So here's the deal: I tried a couple of times with and without this code and measured `DomReady` and `Load` events.

The `DomReady` event fires around the same time (before: **1.58s**, after: **1.60s**)

The `Load` event on the other hand fires waaay earlier (before: **8.19s**, after: **1.92s**)

In a way, this doesn't *actually* improve loading-speed, of course - anyway, in my opinion. the user experience is improved. Any comments or suggestions?